# Was bedeutet »den Düwel ook«?

Tags: etymology, semantics, low-german

Ich weiß schon, dass »den Düwel ook« nicht literarisches Deutsch ist.

Trotzdem wollte ich wissen, was das bedeutet. Und besonders wollte ich die Etymologie des Worts *ook* wissen.

> »Je, den Düwel ook, c’est la question, ma très chère demoiselle!«

(Buddenbrooks)

Comment: Yes, "ook" means auch here. First sentence of Thomas Mann's Buddenbrooks, this is Plattdeutsch. It shall mark the situation of the family in Lübeck.

Comment: Ist das überhaupt Deutsch (ein deutscher Dialekt)? Das einzige Wort, das mir einigermaßen deutsch erscheint, ist »den«. Den größten Teil des Zitats würde ich aber für Französisch halten. Wenn das nämlich nicht Deutsch ist, ist die Frage hier off-topic. (Fragen zu deutsche Dialekten sind aber natürlich erlaubt und erwünscht.)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast nach dem hinteren, französischen Teil wurde nicht gefragt und der Anfang klingt für mich nach Plattdeutsch (auch wenn ich mich als Schwabe nicht qualifiziert fühle, eine Antwort zu schreiben, das überlasse ich anderen). Ergo: on-topic.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast. Platt ist ein deutscher Dialekt.

Comment: @HuberSchölnast Wie gesagt, das ist der erste Satz in Thomas Manns Buddenbroooks und Plattdeutsch

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Du hast gerade den tag "plattdeutsch' gesetzt, gab es den schon? Bisher ist dies die einzige Frage dazu, wohingegen der tag 'northern-german' schon ganze 7 Fragen hat. Wrder der besser passen?

Comment: @Marzipanherz Danke für den Hinweis. Den tag gab es noch nicht, ich habe ihn neu gesetzt. Ich tendiere dazu "plattdeutsch" und "norther-german" als zwei verschiedene Dinge anzusehen; aber die bisher mit "northern-german" getaggten Threads behandeln z.T. auch plattdetusch... Also, wie gesagt, ich bin unschlüssig.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Vielleicht kannst Du eine Diskussion darüber auf Meta starten?  Vielleicht finden sich dort genügend Sprach- und .SE-Experten, die das klären können

Comment: @Marzipanherz Ja, gute Idee, hab ich glatt gemacht: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1246/which-tag-shall-be-used-for-questions-concerning-plattdeutsch

Comment: @fdb Plattdeutsch ist kein Dialekt, sondern eine Sprache und steht in der Liste der [Europäischen Charta der Regional- und Minderheitensprachen](https://www.coe.int/t/dg4/education/minlang/AboutCharter/LanguagesCovered_de.pdf).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wie User @gnasher729 richtig kommentiert hat, ist die Phrase plattdeutsch und bedeutet "den Teufel auch".

Der plattdeutsche Dialekt passt zur Handlung des Romans in einer Hansestadt.

Online-Worterbücher wie [www.deutsch-plattdeutsch.de](http://www.deutsch-plattdeutsch.de/) listen "Düwel" als eine mögliche Schreibweise für "Teufel" und "ook" als "auch.

Da Dich die Ethymologie des Wortes "ook" interessiert:
[wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ook#Etymology_3) gibt für die niederländische Version von "ook" an:

> From Middle Dutch *ooc*, from Old Dutch *ōk*, *ouk*, from Proto-Germanic **auk*. Cognate with German *auch*

*ook/auch* wird oft auch als Beispiel für die Zweite Lautverschiebung in der deutschen Sprache genannt (siehe [Wikipedia.org](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweite_Lautverschiebung)), durch die die hochdeutschen Dialekte entstanden und sich von den niederdeutschen Dialekten abgrenzten.

Answer (score 0):

In all Germanic branches except German: *ook* s.v. means "and, further", as in Dutch and Old English, which are closely related to Low German. This makes no sense here. The polysemous conjunction/adverb *auch* "as well" may be read as intensifier. Compare "Zum Teufel *noch eins*", "auch noch", over the more frequently bare "zum Teufel", "was zur Hölle" as in many other languages. That is however difficult to conceive of as the original state of affairs.

I propose instead to read *look*, *Loch* "hole" and compare "am Arsch" or "Höllenschlund", as well as English "down the drain", "go to pots", Low German "Potzblitz", ... as the sink loo could rightfully be understood as the abyss of human nature.

Comment: Falls es Dir entgangen ist, die Frage war auf Deutsch.

Comment: ist mir entgangen, aber auch egal. Den Titel könnten immerhin auch andere klicken.